# Overriding a Magento Controller in community extension

Tags: magento, controller, overriding

I have the extension CreativeStyle CheckoutByAmazon installed on my magento 1.7 store and I am trying to override the CheckoutController Class but magento seems to ignore my override. Any suggestions will be much appreciated. Also cleared cache but still doesnt work

(In app/code/local Folder)

MyModule
  \CheckoutByAmazon
      \controllers
          \CheckoutController.php
      \etc
          \config.xml

(app/etc/config.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkoutbyamazon>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon before="Creativestyle_CheckoutByAmazon">MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon</MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkoutbyamazon>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

(In app/code/local/MyModule/CheckoutByAmazon/controllers/CheckoutController)

```
<?php
//Controllers are not autoloaded so we will have to do it manually:
require_once 'Creativestyle/CheckoutByAmazon/controllers/CheckoutController.php';

class MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon_CheckoutController extends Creativestyle_CheckoutByAmazon_CheckoutController {

    public function indexAction() {
       exit('I am here');
        parent::indexAction();
    }

    //i want to override this function
      public function saveShippingAction() {
       //insert my overriding code
        exit('saveShipping');
        }

}
?>
```

(In etc/modules/MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please confirm that the community extension is `Creativestyle_ MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon` and not `CreativeStyle_ MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon`.

Comment: dont fully understand your comment. The extension is located at app/code/community/Creativestyle/CheckoutByAmazon and mine is at app/code/local/MyModule/CheckoutByAmazon. Is my file path the problem?

Comment: the first code's file path shoulw be app/code/local/MyModule/CheckoutByAmazon/etc/config.xml

Comment: You stated "I have the extension CreativeStyle CheckoutByAmazon" but then you list orig. code under Creativestyle; just wanted to confirm. Where is your module config.xml file?

Comment: module's config file located in following file path app/code/local/MyModule/CheckoutByAmazon/etc/config.xml . Did you have any luck overriding the CheckoutController. I want to override the SaveShippingAction in the CheckoutController

Comment: Please add the *config.xml* file from `Creativestyle_CheckoutByAmazon` to your question. There are a couple of potential reasons that this isn't working.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Creativestyle_CheckoutByAmazon>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Creativestyle_Core/>
                <Mage_Catalog/>
                <Mage_Checkout/>
                <Mage_Directory/>
                <Mage_Eav/>
                <Mage_Payment/>
                <Mage_Sales/>
            </depends>
        </Creativestyle_CheckoutByAmazon>
    </modules>
</config>`

Answer (score 9):

**tl;dr: The original extension config is likely the problem, but here's how to troubleshoot.**

In order to begin debugging it's necessary to understand what you are trying to do. Without any custom modules in present, Magento will take the request path frontname "checkout", match it to the directory *./app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/* and then look for a match of the second and third parameters as a combination of file, class definition in that file, and action method in that class. Non-deprecated rewrite syntax (which you are trying to perform with your module) simply ***adds an additional directory for matching***. Before debugging this, it's best to cover the basics. This presents a good opportunity to debug controller overrides.

There are a number of preconditions which must be satisfied (your module's *config.xml* getting merged, correct syntax & file structure, etc.). It's good to test that these are working first, as it will reduce and pinpoint the areas where we need to debug.

In a *test.php* file in your Magento root, do the following:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_STRICT);
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app();

$origDir = Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Creativestyle_CheckoutByAmazon').DS;
require_once $origDir.'CheckoutController.php';

$controller = new MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon_CheckoutController(
    Mage::app()->getRequest(),    //required constructor arg
    Mage::app()->getResponse()    //required constructor arg
);

echo get_class($controller);
```

Visit yoursite.com/test.php and you should see your controller class name. If you see an error, or you see nothing, something fairly low-level is broken. If the error message is unintuitive, check that your module config is being merged and move from there.

If the class instantiates, we know the following:

1. Base module config is good
2. File structure is appropriate for the config
3. The explicit include is good

My suspicion is that you will make it this far, because I believe the issue to be config-based. There are a few possibilities. To gain insight, amend *test.php* to the following (assuming PHP >= 5.3):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_STRICT);
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app();

$router = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRouter('standard');
/* @var $router Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard */

$reflection = new ReflectionClass($router);
$modules = $reflection->getProperty('_modules');
$modules->setAccessible(true);

var_dump($modules->getValue($router));
```

The output should resemble something like the following:

```
array(35) {
  ["core"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "Mage_Core"
  }
  ["install"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "Mage_Install"
  }
  ["directory"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "Mage_Directory"
  }
  // ...
  ["checkout"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "Mage_Checkout"
  }
  // ...
}
```

Wherever you see more than one subarray, there is a controller directory rewrite.

Comment: will try this out and post results

Comment: @benmarks, I have a similar issue as the OP here and I have followed your suggestions but cannot find a solution. I have created a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22667379/overriding-magento-third-party-controller-in-custom-module)

Comment: And what would you suggest when your module passes both of these tests, but still isn't used by Magento in favor of the community module?

Comment: To expand on my comment, I've run both of these reflection tests and pass them, but am still having issues with the module not being used by Magento. Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122202/problems-overriding-magento-community-module-controller

Comment: Thank you bemarks. Your answer is saved my time a lot  ... :)

Comment: @benmarks - my code cannot pass second test, getting only single value in array.. so how to fix it. Posted my code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620321/overriding-csmarketplace-account-controller-with-a-custom-controller

Answer (score 4):

To complete C4rter's answer, here is the full code you have to add into your config.xml file :

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <checkoutbyamazon>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon before="Creativestyle_CheckoutByAmazon_Adminhtml">MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon</MyModule_CheckoutByAmazon>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkoutbyamazon>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

You don't need the frontend rewrite part.

Comment: Thank you both for the answer. I had the same situation and now it works thank to your answer. However I didn't get it. This is a *frontend* route and we just need to add an *admin* route? Can you please help me understand this?

Answer (score 2):

Tried to do the same and failed also. But I found the reason. The CheckoutByAmazon Extension has an admincontroller of the same name:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <checkoutbyamazon>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Creativestyle_CheckoutByAmazon</module>
                <frontName>checkoutbyamazon</frontName>
            </args>
        </checkoutbyamazon>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

So you have to rewrite the admin controller:

```
before="Creativestyle_CheckoutByAmazon_Adminhtml"
```