# Overriding Magento Third Party Controller In Custom Module

Tags: php, magento

I am writing a Magento extension that is trying to override a third party extensions `IndexController.php` but Magento does not recognize it.

I have a similar issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814708/overriding-a-magento-controller-in-community-extention) and I have tried benmarks suggestions but Magento still seems to be ignoring my override.

My `config.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <Mycompany_Stores>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mycompany_Stores>
  </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <storepickup>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mycompany_Stores before="Magestore_Storepickup">Mycompany_Stores</Mycompany_Stores>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </storepickup>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

And my `IndexController.php` looks like this:

```
<?php

require_once('Magestore/Storepickup/controllers/IndexController.php');
class Mycompany_Stores_IndexController extends Magestore_Storepickup_IndexController {

    public function indexAction() {
      var_dump('asdfasdfsdf');  
      parent::indexAction();
  }
}
```

Following benmarks first suggestion from the linked post above, I get an error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: include(Mycompany/Stores/IndexController.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream:...`

But following the second suggestion, I get:

```
["storepickup"] => array(2) {
    [0] => string(14) "Mycompany_Stores"
    [1] => string(21) "Magestore_Storepickup"
}
```

So it appears that there is an override, but I cannot figure out why my `indexAction()` or any other method is not getting called.

**EDIT:** Defining my own route in my `config.xml` file is working when I go to www.site.com/stores:

```
<stores> 
    <use>standard</use>
    <args>
        <module>Mycompany_Stores</module>
        <frontName>stores</frontName>
    </args>
</stores>
```

I still cannot figure out why My controller is not overriding the extension though. I have been able to override blocks within this same module, just not the controller.

Comment: I think `require_once('Magestore/Storepickup/controllers/IndexController.php';` is seems to be making problem here. Please comment that line and try again. also see you didnt close the `(`.

Comment: Good catch on the missing `)`. I've tried with and without the `require_once` but nothing changed.

Comment: ok did you go through the other solutions that are available in the referenced link.. Since your overriding is success, there may be another controller which take chance of suppressed one. Please comment your require line of code and add `echo "test";die();`( and avoid rest code till you obtain the result)inside indexAction() - this is for testing purpose

Comment: +1 for clear and crisp presentation of your prob  :)

Comment: I've added `echo 'test';die()` to the first line of my modules `IndexController.php` file but still don't get anything.

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with the include that is being output in the fatal error I'm getting. `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: include(Mycompany/Stores/IndexController.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. It's trying to include the file from Mycompany/Stores/IndexController.php, but should be Mycompany/Stores/controllers/IndexController.php

Comment: Using the first script from my other post, rathern than `require_once`, what is the return value of `echo $origDir.'CheckoutController.php'; die;`?

Comment: @benmarks, I get the full path to the module's controller I'm trying to overwrite, `/home/user/site/app/code/community/Magestore/Storepickup/controllers/IndexController.php`

Comment: `$origDir` should be assigned with `Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mycompany_Stores').DS;` Seems like that's not the case B-)

Comment: @benmarks, Ahh ok. In your answer to the linked question it had the module that was trying to be overridden's name in it. Either way, this returned an instantiated object of my controller class, but still does not explain why my controller is not being called when I navigate to www.site.com/storepickup/index/index. (storepickup is the `frontName` for the module I am attempting to override)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your diagnostic steps and the info in the comment thread your rewrite should be working. The most important step is to get the XPath correct, and

```
["storepickup"] => array(2) {
    [0] => string(14) "Mycompany_Stores"
    [1] => string(21) "Magestore_Storepickup"
}
```

tells us that you have done just that, and that your module's *`controllers`* directory is properly listed to effect an override.

Normally I would suspect a redirect or something similar in the parent class `indexAction()`, but due to you echoing directly from your controller action `var_dump()` the redirect header wouldn't be able to be set. Still, I would be inclined to perform the three following diagnostic steps:

1. Change your `indexAction()` body to `die(__FILE__);`
2. You can also test standard controller functionality by defining your own route and frontname and accessing your controller that way at */frontname/*
3. Create a method `fooAction()` same as above and call the URL */storepickup/index/foo/*

Comment: I defined my own frontname in my `config.xml` file and that is working, just not the override. I have updated my question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already tried, I would put in a dependency tag into your `app/etc/modules/MyCompany_MyModule.xml` file, something like:

```
 ... 
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Magestore_Storepickup/>  <!-- load after Magestore_Storepickup -->
        </depends>
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have already tried with and without the depends.

Comment: `<depends />` affects configuration load order, which occasionally does have precedence effects down the road. For controllers though the  `//modules/[node @before]` attribute value will set precedence in this case.