# magento how to rewrite checkout community controller

Tags: controller, magento-1.9

i've been trying to override the checkout controller from  a community extension for 2 hours, and still not working.

My Custom module is activated .
Trying to rewrite (Community/Manv/Ajaxcoupon/controllers/Indexcontroller.php)
Here is my controller.

```
require_once 'Manv/Ajaxcoupon/controllers/IndexController.php';

    class Name_Promocode_CartController extends Manv_Ajaxcoupon_IndexController
    {

        public function customcouponPostAction(){
            die('custom');
        }

        public function couponPostAction()
        {
            die('We are in');
    }
```

Here is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Name_Promocode>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Name_Promocode>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
          <checkout>
            <args>
              <modules>
                <Name_Promocode before="Manv_Ajaxcoupon">Name_Promocode</Name_Promocode>
              </modules>
            </args>
          </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Deleted cache...
Can't find what's wrong, when i put a die() in the community module, i see it. But seems like my module isn't overriding anythings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made it works with  this config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Name_Promocode>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Name_Promocode>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
          <name_promocode>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Name_Promocode</module>
                    <frontName>promocode</frontName>
                </args>
          </name_promocode>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <name_promocode> 
                <from><![CDATA[#^/ajaxcoupon/index/#]]></from>  <!-- the URL which u want to override-->
                <to>/promocode/cart/</to>  <!-- destination url -->
            </name_promocode>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
</config>
```

Hope this will help someone :D

Answer (score 0):

// Try compare with below config.xml code.

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <name_promocode before="Mage_Tag">Manv_Ajaxcoupon</name_promocode>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </tag>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

//Alternate override controller code.

```
  <global>
        <!-- This rewrite rule could be added to the database instead -->
        <rewrite>
            <!-- This is an identifier for your rewrite that should be unique -->
            <!-- THIS IS THE CLASSNAME IN YOUR OWN CONTROLLER -->
            <customcontactsunique>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/contacts/index/#]]></from>
                <!--
                    - mymodule matches the router frontname below
                    -  matches the path to your controller

                    Considering the router below, "/customcontacts/index/" will be
                    "translated" to "app/code/local/Amit/Customcontacts/controllers/IndexController.php" (?)
                -->
                <to>/customcontacts/index/</to>
            </customcontactsunique>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
```

//compare controller code.

```
    require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Manv_Ajaxcoupon').DS.'IndexController.php');

class Name_Promocode_CartController extends Manv_Ajaxcoupon_IndexController
{
  // some code
}
```

[More reference](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)

[Alternate override controller link](http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento/)

Comment: Thx i ll try it now

Comment: Compared to this i had on some upperCase char after <modules>. Changed them to :` <frontend>
  <routers>
    <checkout>
      <args>
        <modules>
          <wishibam_promocode before="Manv_Ajaxcoupon">Wishibam_Promocode</wishibam_promocode>
        </modules>
      </args>
    </checkout>
  </routers>
 </frontend>`

Comment: Worked from your side ?

Comment: Still not overriding...trying somethings else from your References

Comment: First check your module present and enable in admin. system->advance->modules.

Comment: Everythings is good there, im trying From TO method to override the controller. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122202/problems-overriding-magento-community-module-controller?rq=1

Comment: Edited my answer. added alternate rewrite controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Name_Promocode>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Name_Promocode>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
          <name_promocode>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Name_Promocode</module>
                    <frontName>promocode</frontName>
                </args>
          </name_promocode>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <name_promocode> 
                <from><![CDATA[#^/ajaxcoupon/index/#]]></from>  <!-- the URL which u want to override-->
                <to>/promocode/cart/</to>  <!-- destination url -->
            </name_promocode>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
</config>
```